# Continuous sync of photos from AD to AAD using AAD Connect tool

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

Need to continuously sync(not just once) photos of users into AD environment, and then into Azure AD.  According to the article below, this attribute is only synced one time on initial sync.  These photos are updated by our Security group when someone gets a new badge and then we update the photo in AD.  Can they sync these ongoing, on a continuous basis, using the AD Connect tool?  If so, do we have a document that can assist my customer with this type of configuration/need?

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/3062745/user-photos-aren-t-synced-from-the-on-premises-environment-to-exchange

Answer (score 0):

As stated in the article, for now, the only method I see available for you to use, is the Set-UserPhoto cmdlet.

Br,